# Is nodejs mandatory for angular2, can I run with apache server?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm-install

I am using angular2 with nodejs, how about using apache/xampp. will it support or nodejs npm server is mandatory for angular2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Considering for development ,NodeJS is Mandatory for angular2  !

let me tell you why?

Angular2 comes with typescript support which is transpiled into javascript.

NodeJS offers typings & other dependency packages like `SystemJS,RxJS` which helps angular2 do thye magic you call `Angular`.

Though you could run angular2 apps in Xampp but recommended approach will be with NodeJS as it offers a lot more flexibility & framework support for development.

for eg. `Angular-Cli` is node module which helps you setup your project really fast.

On top of that node gives you flexibilty to add third party libraries easily into your project.

You can use Xampp but then you will need your server to load transpiler manually which will transpile ts files into javascript files as currently there is no support in Xampp as far as I know and that will be quite a task to do.

So I will go with NodeJS on this.

> For production:

once you build bundle from your application , it can be deployed to any server which runs javascript. So in that case NodeJS is not required.

Comment: Thanks, I see angular2 in js ts and dart. which one is the best to adopt. I know js and jquery and personally I feel ts to be good. Please help me with your suggestion

Comment: personally I will recommend ts as it has vast support and angular people have made it official language for angular2. Its easy & had rich support for modules & you can use js libraries directly inside ts.  @Karthikeyansundaramoorthi

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what we are talking about.

For **Development** you *must* have NodeJS on your dev machine to load all libs, transpile TS, prepare build files and so on.

For **Production server** you can use whatever you want, if you have already prepared js bundles with all deps and your app, just static files with index.html, css, js, jpg files and so on..

Answer (score 2):

I will also recommend you to go with Oleg Barinov.More over Angular2 applications only consist of static files so they can be serve by any static Web servers or server applications that can define static folders (Express, ...)